# loop through variables to create interaction terms

Tags: sas

I seek to loop through variables (can be contained in a macro variable or a data set) to create a macro variable with interaction terms that I can use in a regression. Here is an example.

Let’s say the original variables are in a  macro variable.

```
%let predictors = age sex bmi;
```

I seek to loop through these variables and create a macro variable that I  can use in a regression.

In the first iteration, we have age. I seek to create:

```
% interactions = age sex bmi sex*age bmi*age
```

Fit a regression.

Then use sex in the next iteration.

```
% interactions = age sex bmi age*sex bmi*sex;
```

And so on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note really sure how you are using this, but a simple `%do` loop should handle your request.

```
%macro test(predictors);
%local n i j ;
%let n=%sysfunc(countw(&predictors));
%do i=1 %to &n;
  %let interactions=&predictors;
  %do j=1 %to &n;
    %if &i^=&j %then %let interactions=
       &interactions %scan(&predictors,&i)*%scan(&predictors,&j)
    ;
  %end;
  %put &=i &=interactions;
%end;
%mend ;
%test(age sex bmi);
```

Which produces this list to the log.

```
I=1 INTERACTIONS=age sex bmi age*sex age*bmi
I=2 INTERACTIONS=age sex bmi sex*age sex*bmi
I=3 INTERACTIONS=age sex bmi bmi*age bmi*sex
```

Answer (score 1):

The model statement of many SAS PROCs supports a syntax for that.  The pipe is all crossings while @2 limits the interactions to 2 way. Leave off the @ for all.

```
proc glm data=sashelp.class;
   class sex;
   model age=sex|height|weight@2;
   run;
   quit;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Does this address the fact that the list of predictors will change as one iterates through the original list of variables?

Comment: Are talking about some kind step-wise model?

Comment: For each iteration, I will be fitting a logistic model, collecting some information about this model, and then moving onto the next iteration. At each iteration, the variables will change as outlined in my question. Let me know my question can be made more clear.

Comment: @julieth no it doesn't do it by testing the interaction terms one by one as your proposing. Unless you have a specific protocol that requires this, I don't know that this process would be required.